# Children's book about a Pig that buys a duck from the market to eat, takes the Duck home and they eat peas together

Tags: identification-request

This would have been in circulation in Australia in the 1980's, possibly a book club / scholastic book. A pig goes to the market to buy a duck to eat for dinner, takes the duck home and they both eat peas for dinner instead.
I recall it being a medium to large softcover with good illustrations (possibly watercolour) and not that long of a book definitely more picture based.